# How to return new array with deleted values python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I try to get new array without the 2's from first array, of course it is possible with many ways, but I'm looking for fewer coding and smarter solution, this array as example..:

```
somearray = np.array( [4, 5, 2, 8, 4, 7, 2, 64, 2, 57, 2, 45, 7, 43, 2, 5, 7, 3, 3, 6523, 3, 4, 3, 0, -65, -343])
#so create array for deleted 2's for the new array only, the first one will not be affected.
newarray = ??
```

please don't answer me "`np.ma.masked_array(vec, vec == 2)`" it will replace the 2's with `--` without deleting them..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`argwhere()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) method for finding indices of 2 in your array:

```
indices=np.argwhere(somearray==2)
```

Now Finally make use of [`delete()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) method:

```
newarray=np.delete(somearray,indices[1:])
```

Now if you print `newarray` you will get your desired output:

```
array([   4,    5,    2,    8,    4,    7,   64,   57,   45,    7,   43,
          5,    7,    3,    3, 6523,    3,    4,    3,    0,  -65, -343])
```

Comment: ok you are right, as a new python developer that was duplicated question I guess, whatever you got the correct answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

use a regular expression to find all values equally 2 and ignore.

```
 import re

 original_array = np.array( [4, 5, 2, 8, 4, 7, 2, 64, 2, 57, 2, 45, 7, 43, 2, 5, 7, 3, 3, 6523, 3, 4, 3, 0, -65, -343])
 digit_re = re.compile('[2]{1}')
 [print (x) for x in original_array if not digit_re.search(str(x))]
```